# Convert hierarchical sort method to an extension in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, parent-child, extension-methods, hierarchical-data

I have a method that sorts a parent-child list into a hierarchy. It works great, but is possible to convert this into a generic extension method?

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>( );

tasks.Add( new Task { Id = 1, ParentId = null, Title = "" } );
tasks.Add( new Task { Id = 2, ParentId = 4, Title = "" } );
tasks.Add( new Task { Id = 3, ParentId = 2, Title = "" } );
tasks.Add( new Task { Id = 4, ParentId = null, Title = "" } );
tasks.Add( new Task { Id = 5, ParentId = 2, Title = "" } );
tasks.Add( new Task { Id = 6, ParentId = null, Title = "" } );
tasks.Add( new Task { Id = 7, ParentId = 6, Title = "" } );
```

The method:

```
var lookup = tasks.ToLookup( x => x.ParentId );

IEnumerable<Task> heirarchySort( int? pid ) => lookup[pid]
    .SelectMany(
        x => new[] { x }.Concat( heirarchySort( x.Id ) )
    );

IEnumerable<Task> sortedTasks = heirarchySort( null );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share a [mcve], to avoid each of us trying to help to have to guess what the relevant classes look like etc etc.

Comment: Will do @mjwills.

Comment: Also be clear what the expected _output_ is.

Comment: I see that your using x.Id, so the only way to make it generic is to have an interface "IIdentifiable" witch defines an Id property

Comment: @Orkad +ParentId. As an alternative to defining an interface, one may pass two expressions to the method to access Id and ParentId.

Comment: @KlausGütter yes ofc i forgot the ParentId, i suggest an interface but he can use a base class { Id, ParentId }

Comment: Your parent-child list defines a tree. There are multiple ways to define "order" on a tree (e.g. DFS, BFS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution uses two expressions to access the Id and ParentId of the items; the order returned if depth-first as in your code:

```
static class Extension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DFS<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, int> getId, Func<T, int?> getParentId)
    {
        var lookup = list.ToLookup(x => getParentId(x));
        IEnumerable<T> hierarchySort(int? pid) => lookup[pid].SelectMany(x => new[] { x }.Concat(hierarchySort(getId(x))));
        return hierarchySort(null);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<Task> sortedTasks = tasks.DFS(t => t.Id, t => t.ParentId);
```

it still hard-codes the type of `Id` as `int`; this could be made an additional template parameter if needed.

Comment: Thanks @Klaus. That's exactly what I was looking for. Getting the parameters into the extension now seems really straightforward - it wasn't at the time of composing the question!